# Add progressbar loader when Video is loading in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

By default exoplayer is not showing this progress loader on video while it is loading. I have tried many codea but not working.

Comment: Hi, if the post below did help you, please click the answer validation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method from the PlayerView class:

```
 setShowBuffering(boolean showBuffering)
```

/**

- Sets whether a buffering spinner is displayed when the player is in the buffering state. The
- buffering spinner is not displayed by default.
- 
- @param showBuffering Whether the buffering icon is displayer
  */

It is also an attribute that you can set in the XML layout: show_buffering

**EDIT 2021**
As mentionned below by @Rohaitas Tanoli the code above is now deprecated.
Here is the updated code:

```
setShowBuffering(PlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_ALWAYS)
```

Comment: dont exist setShowBuffering for PlayerView!

Comment: Yes it does exist. See on exoplayer website: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setShowBuffering-int-

Comment: but in my xml file does not shown, like this picture:
https://pasteboard.co/IaxBp3p.png

Comment: This is depreciated.  playerView.setShowBuffering(true);
use playerView.setShowBuffering(PlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_ALWAYS);

Comment: Thank you for the information @RohaitasTanoli , I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use    `app:show_buffering` in layout file and values are
`never` = The buffering view is never shown.
`always` = The buffering view is always shown when the player is in the buffering state.
`when_playing`=The buffering view is shown when the player is in the buffering state and playWhenReady is true.

Here is the link https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING